# I want to convert date array coming from bootstrap date picker to PHP date in yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: php, laravel, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I am getting following dates from the bootstrap date picker in my laravel backend.

```
[start_date] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2018
        [month] => 2
        [day] => 1
    )

[end_date] => Array
    (
        [year] => 2018
        [month] => 4
        [day] => 30
    )
```

I want to convert the date in to php date i.e

```
start_date = "2018-02-01";
end_date = "2018-04-30"
```

If anyone is providing answers please provide the specific code or links.

Comment: Do you recieve this date as one array or  multi array ($start_date,$end_date)

Comment: i recieve as associative array

Comment: yeh i see it from your  answer Thanks dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  implode to avoid long code:

```
$get_start_date = implode('-',$RequestData['start_date'])  
$get_end_date = implode('-',$RequestData['end_date'])  

$start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($get_start_date));
$end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($get_end_date));
```

Comment: true that i totally forgot this :D

Comment: Yep the more code is short is good for execution time please mark it as answer for helping people

Comment: yes i did already please mark my question as same

Comment: Done, i dont know why people voting down when is the post usefull for others :D

Comment: seriously i got  my reputation down man it hurts :D

Comment: yeh it happen to me Too sometimes ,there is this kind of people , good look with your coding dude

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173613/discussion-between-sagar-ahuja-and-nighamza).

Answer (score 0):

You can use date_create PHP Function :

```
$start_date=date_create($date['start_date']->year.'-'.$date['start_date']->month.$date['start_date']->day);
$start_date=$start_date->format('Y-m-d')

$end_date=date_create($date['end_date']->year.'-'.$date['end_date']->month.$date['end_date']->day);
$end_date=$end_date->format('Y-m-d')
```

Comment: thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon

```
$s_date = \Carbon\Carbon::create($start_date[0], $start_date[1], 
$start_date[2],0,0,0);
```

Comment: thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Carbon is best to use https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

```
$dt = Carbon::create($year, $month, $day);
echo $dt->toDateString();
```